# Eclipse command to close/start my plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So I am working on my first Eclipse plugin, and I want to have the possibility of closing the plugin(or deactivating it).

Now I read here and there about bindings and commands, I managed to get the binding(CTRL+4) appear in the **Eclipse->Preferences->Keys**.

But can't seem to know how to implement the **execute** method from the class implementing the **IHandler** to actually close my plugin.

In the code below, you can see my attempts of getting something displayed, but they also don't work..

```
     <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            id="com.myplugin.myCategory"
            name="Category" 
            description="a description">
      </category>   
      <command
            defaultHandler="mypackage.ExitHandler"
            id="myproject.exit"
            categoryId="com.myplugin.myCategory"
            name="Close Plugin">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="myproject.exit"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="M1+4">
      </key>
   </extension>



public class ExitHandler implements IHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
         MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(
                 event).getShell(), "Info", "Info for you");
         System.out.println("I wanna exittttttttttttttt");
        return null;
    }
}
```

So any ideas on how to close and then start a plugin that I've created using this approach?
Is it enough if I implement just the execute method..?

Dan

SOLUTION

So as Gred said in a comment below, I should have extended  `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler` and implement the `execute` method.

Comment: `IHandler` has a lot more methods than that, what have you done for the other methods? It is normal to extended `AbstractHandler` which provides default implementations of most methods. It is very unusual to start and stop plugins.

Comment: Hi Greg..thx for the help these last few days. 1.I haven't done anything with the other methods..couldn't find an example online about this. 2.According to documentation `org.eclipse.ui.commands Class AbstractHandler` is deprecated.. My plugin displays some text when the user hovers over method names or variables..I was thinking that in some conditions, the user might not want to see that text..

Comment: @greg-449 But there are other approaches that can work in my case..I could for example delete the text that is displayed during hover, and in that case, the Eclipse functionality of the hover works. However, I need to do this using a key binding and a command right?

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler` is the correct class. Just not displaying something is very different from telling Eclipse to stop a plugin. Just set a flag somewhere in the command handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

So as Gred said in a comment below, I should have extended **org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler** and implement the execute method.